# Is my limit development correct?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I have this limit to find:

> $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x}-1}{x}$

My development was:

Let $\large{u^n = 1+x}$, from here if $x\to 0$ implies that $\large{u^n \to 1}$

And i got: $\Large{\lim_{u^n \to 1}\frac{u-1}{u^n - 1}}$ and using that $\Large{u^n - 1 = (u-1)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{u^j}}$

Finally i got $\Large{\lim_{u^n\to1}\frac{1}{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{u^j}} = \dfrac{1}{n}}$

I know that the result is correct, but i want to know if all my steps are correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Your work is correct. You could make it shorter using the binomial expansion $\sqrt[n] {1+x}=1+\frac{x}{n}+\frac{(1-n) x^2}{2 n^2}+O\left(x^3\right)$ which will show that the expression is $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(1-n) x}{2 n^2}+O\left(x^2\right)$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Comment: Well you just write $u\to 1$ instead of $u^n\to 1$. Rest is fine.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Why write $\large{u\to 1}$ instead of $\large{u^n \to 1}$? Is a convention or what?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks for your solution

Comment: The limit notation is $\lim\limits_{\text{variable} \to\text{value} } $. Here $u$ is a variable and $u^n$ is a function of the variable $u$. The limit notation does not allow for $\lim\limits_{\text{function} \to\text{value}} $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I can't see your latex

Comment: It's visible in my browser. Try refreshing whole page.

Comment: I already did, it's just your comment. It's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are correct except you write $u\to 1$ instead of $u^n\to 1$.  Here is another simple approach 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x}-1}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/n}-1}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\cdot x+\left(\frac1n\right)\left(\frac1n-1\right)\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots\right)-1}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(1-n)x}{2n^2}+\ldots\right)$$
$$=\frac1n$$

Comment: Why write $\large{u\to 1}$ instead of $\large{u^n \to 1}$? Is a convention or what?

Comment: well, you have have assumed a new variable $u$ not $u^{n}$ so you should express limit for $u$.